# Match list of regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I have list of regular expressions like below:

```
regexes = [   
    re.compile(r"((intrigued)(.*)(air))"),
    re.compile(r"(air|ipadair)(.*)(wishlist|wish)"),
    re.compile(r"(replac(ed|ing|es|.*)(.*)(with)(.*)(air))"),
    re.compile(r"(upgrade)")]
for regex in regexes:
      if regex.search(post):
           print 1
           break
```

Suppose I have a long list of strings and I want to search for these regex in each of my string, if any of the regex matched return 1 and break. Then do the same thing for the next string. My current one is running super slow, please let me know if there are any better alternatives.

Thanks,

Comment: regex _is_ slow. in my experience, just doing `re.search(substr, str)` is about an order of magnitude slower than `substr in str` - and your regexes are much more complicated than that. i don't think you will get much speedup from this, but you could accomplish something similar with `any(regex.search(post) for regex in regexes)`.. it's not really faster, just simpler.

Comment: Do some benchmarking to find out which of your regexes return fastest on average, then apply them in that sorted order. Might also be worth trying pre-filtering e.g. on the first letter, if that makes sense for your inputs and regexes.

Comment: The third regexp contains |.*)(.*) which is particularly dead-slow.

Answer (score 2):

As some of the comments have mentioned, this looks like it might not be a job for regexes. I think it's worth looking at what you are actually trying to do here. Take a look one of the regexes:

```
"(air|ipadair)(.*)(wishlist|wish)"
```

In this case we are matching "air" or "ipadair", but just "air" would match both. The same is true for "wish". As we are not making use of the capture groups the output could be simplified to:

```
"air.*wish"
```

The same is true of all of the other patterns, which begs the question: what is this regex actually doing?

It looks like you just want to see if certain patterns of words appear in an order in your article. If that is true, then we can achieve this much faster in python without regexes:

```
def has_phrases(in_string, phrases):
    for words in phrases:
        start = 0
        match = True

        # Match all words
        for word in words:
            # Each word must come after the ones before
            start = in_string.find(word, start)
            if start == -1:
                match = False
                break

        if match:
            return True

phrases = [
    ['upgrade'],
    ['air', 'wish'],
    ['intrigued', 'air'],
    ['replac', 'with', 'air' ],
]

print has_phrases("... air ... wish ...", phrases)      # True!
print has_phrases("... horse ... magic ...", phrases)   # None
```

Of course, if you were just giving a simplified example and you plan to use crazy complicated regexes, this won't cut it.

Hope that helps!